# sql plus query to return data after a carriage return in a string

Tags: sqlplus

I have a field in oracle database which contained the following string:

**Description**:
This is first line (ABC)
This is second line (123)

Under the oracle table, it is displayed as one line without a space:

**"this is first line (ABC)This is second line (123)"**

The first line is ended with carriage return.

How to export only the second line (after a carriage return) and ignore the first line?

Answer (score 0):

this is just a rough idea, hopefully it can guide you:

```
str = "this is first line (ABC)This is second line (123)";

SELECT SUBSTR(str, INSTR(str, '\n')) from dual;
```